# How to use in clause in order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here][1]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AvZN.png)

Will special character affect my sorting order?

I tried to solve this query [provided in the image] in SQL Server, then got to know that in clause doesn't work with `order by`.

When I tried to solve it by case, still the output is wrong, as the person with the name 'Desmond Tutu' is displaying at first position. Can anybody tell me the reason for this.

I solved by giving three priority which is not desired.
Can anyone help me solving this query please.
Thanks !

Comment: The Image is unreadable

Comment: And text is much better than images.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: did you try with where clause putting and

Comment: You have a case expression in your order by but it doesn't cover all the possible values. So for Desmond the value returned from the case expression would be NULL which will sort before 2 or 3.

Comment: @jens click on it then click to magnifty

Comment: I've edited the post. The image had too much blank nothing. So I cut it out.

Comment: I also agree that at least the select statements should be texts though.

Comment: As jarlh pointed out, please type the information as text, not as an image. See here for more info: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I have updated the images, please let me know the resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you are not getting the desired result is that you only push Chemistry and Physics to the end, but leave the rest unsorted - if you don't specify the ordering explicitly the server is free to return the result in whatever order might be practical. Remember that the results from queries are *sets* (or sometimes scalar values) and sets by definition are un-ordered.

As the problem statement is *Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name; but list Chemistry and Physics last.* you need to include the subject and winner name in the ordering.

Also, the exercise is intended to show how the boolean return value of the `in` clause can be used to affect the order, and the correct query, taking that into account, would be:

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984
ORDER BY subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'), subject, winner
```

Comment: I didn't even knew that IN could be used in an order by clause +1. Also, I did a little test here `select....... order by id in (1,2)` in mysql it ordered this two values as last values: table have: 1,2,3,4 and it came 3,4,1,2 is that normal?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I would guess that would be normal as the `id in (1,2)` would return 1 for [1,2] and 0 for [3,4] and hence sort [3,4] first (but the order of  [3,4] is indeterminate and might as well be [4,3], most likely the order of insertion would be used)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks a lot. select winner, subject from nobel order by (case subject when 'Physics' then 3 when 'Chemistry' then 2 end),subject,winner is working fine . Thanks –

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a secondary order on the persons name....

So `ORDER BY firstclause, secondclause`

Also, add an else into your CASE to rank the rest.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks a lot.                                                                                      select winner, subject from nobel
order by (case subject when 'Physics' then 3  when 'Chemistry' then 2 
  end),subject,winner                                                                      is working fine . Thanks